# Is there any way to create a windows installer package in vb.net using tools from microsoft?

Tags: vb.net, windows-installer

I want to create a windows installer package using visual studio. It is my understanding that there was a simple way to do this in vb6, you could add an installer like you can add a new form.

How can I do this in vb.net? I downloaded and installed the Windows SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en because it said somewhere that it could create installer packages and had tools to do so for .net, but no such luck.

I would prefer not to use NSIS or Inno Setup for this.

Is there any way to get the same functionality that you could have in vb6 with the installer packages?

Thanks, I feel I am missing an important step here...

EDIT: I am using visual basic 2008 express, not professional. I dont have "Setup and deployment" or anything like that under my template options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a .msi installer.  Have a look at this question/answer for some more details. [How can I create an MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042566/how-can-i-create-an-msi-setup)

Edit: Others have mentioned WiX, so here's a [link](http://www.dalun.com/wix/01.09.2005.htm) to a tutorial showing how to use it

Answer (score 3):

There is a setup & deployment project type under other when you go to create a new project in VS Standard edition and higher.  If you have express it's not available.

Here's some info on Setup & Deployment projects:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx

Tutorial:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vishnuprasad2005/SetupProjects12022005022406AM/SetupProjects.aspx

Comment: Times like these I wish I had a budget >.<

Comment: Then Glen's answer may be your best bet. Look into WIX. +1 for you Glen. :)

Comment: I don't believe it does although I am not sure since I have never used WIX. You will have to compile your code and use Wix to create the installer for the resulting Exe's, dll's, etc that your program has/uses.

Comment: Another option would be to get your hands on an trial version of VS Pro and create your installer but this is definitely a dangerous option since your trial will run out. Not something I would do but never-the-less an option.

Comment: Well, I have VS 2010, but that says it is "For evaluation purposes only". Would it still work? Its a beta, so it is not under any time constraints. I like Advanced Installer, but I absolutely hate the fact that you cannot control the dialogs which are shown in the Trial version once your 30 days expire.

Comment: Technically speaking if it hasn't disabled capabilities then yes. However, legally speaking is whole different matter and the message is pretty clear so I would say nope. :(

Comment: Yeah, I can't make anything commercial with it then..... Is there a way for me to write my own installer, not necessarily into a .msi? Like, a generic setup.exe? I would like control over the dialogs and how it looks visually, in my opinion a good installer is almost a preview of the product itself.

Comment: I would look to WIX or something like it instead of rolling your own.

Comment: I know, but I am really picky, especially when it comes to using other tools....if I wanted to make my own, how can I compress everything into one file, and then extract it? I know how to make the rest of it, but not the compression/extraction.

Comment: No idea what that is or how to make it.

Answer (score 1):

File -> New Project -> Other Project Types -> Setup and Deployment

Will allow you to add a setup project to any Visual Studio solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio.,Net you would create a Setup Project (or Setup Project Wisard) to create an installer.

Tutorial Here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic58021.htm

Answer (score 1):

Because the express version doesn't include the Setup and Deployment project type, you'll probably find it easier to use a third party tool such as www.advancedinstaller.com - the free version is probably sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I am using that now,but I will switch to Inno setup when my trial expires, cause the one thing that I would really need from advanced installer is only in Enterprise (I want to edit the dialogs), while with Inno setup since I have the source I can add dialogs as needed.