# Linux equivalent of WIX Installer needed

Tags: wix

I have been using Windows Installer XMl V3 in ant scripts for developing Installers(exe or msi). As of now our Build Server is Windows Server 2008 and we are in a process of Moving Build server to RHELv6.3.

That's where problem arises:- Is their anything equivalent to WIX Installer in Linux from where I can make Windows Installer.

I need to use Linux Platform to make Windows Installer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240484/build-msi-in-wine

Comment: https://docs.revenera.com/?product=InstallAnywhere&version=2023%20R1

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is using WINE and Mono as suggested in [Build MSI in Wine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10240484/572834).

Or use a virtual machine with Windows: It's easier to do Windows development on Windows.