# How to create thin setup for Windows MSI Installer?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, thin-client

We have windows application in which we distribute whole MSI package to the client in zip form. We are now up for licensing feature and we want to allow users to work in thin setup just like if you download Visual Studio to install, it will download the files from the server and install it rather than we download whole 20GB VS setup from the server.

We want to use the web-based installer in which we can manage the licensing features too.

Can anyone help or redirect to useful links? It will be a pleasure.

Comment: Can you go to this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042566/how-can-i-create-an-msi-setup

Comment: @brijber I do use WIX and Visual Studio's setup installer for MSI creation, But I want to create a thin setup. Suppose I have 2GB of setup so I just want one user to download 2MB of setup and that setup will download all the necessary files from the server according to the configuration on the server.