# How do I get my python app (compiled using pyinstaller) to appear in the windows start menu?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

As the title says. 
I have used pyinstaller to create my app from the python source code and it works perfectly. I would like to get the app to appear in the start menu but I don't know how to do this?

Comment: I think this is more of a superuser question as it is more related to using windows than development.

Answer (score 2):

Once your app is installed in the Program Files folder, add a new folder in

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\

[image]

Then add a shortcut, .ink, in that folder to the .exe file in Program Files.

[image]

Your program will then show up in the start menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with **pyinstaller**, but it looks like it's main function is to package **Python** code into an executable.

What you are looking for is an installation packager which packs all your files and configs into installations package (eg. `msi`). This package unpacks on the destination system into specified locations and creates all those icons in the start menu and on the desktop and etc.

Take a look at this question: [How can I create an MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042566/how-can-i-create-an-msi-setup)