# Create installer for VS solution ( containing two projects; WPF app and .net standard library)

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a WPF application that is made up of two projects;

1. Main app that contains most of the front-end stuff and the other project is,
2. A .net standard class library that contains the viewmodels

Now I want to create an installer for my solution. I have tried to do so using Installshield.

First, I built the project and copied the .dll generated from the second project ( class library ). Then during the creation of the installer, I imported this library. But the application doesn't function well when I install. I'm having some trouble which to my best guest is that part of the nuget packages used by the class library are missing.

I'll be very grateful if anyone can point me to the right direction on how to create a setup that will include both projects.

[image]

Comment: Assuming that the second project is included as a library in the first you shouldnt have any problem making the deployment by just having the dll in the same folder. What kind of problem are you having?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042566/how-can-i-create-an-msi-setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built the second solution (.net library ) which gave me a .dll file. Then I used Advanced installer to create a setup for my application.