# FilePath locator in setup?

Tags: c#, setup-project

I have made a setup project that I want to use as an installer to my application, of course, the question is though is there any way to get a file path locator box added to the installation? (edit) im trying to make a installer for windows only in this situation and im using vb 2019. Plus im only programming for windows in the situation i am right now.

Comment: Which platform? Operating System? Are you using any setup generator? Which one?

Comment: I added an edit

Comment: I would suggest to use a framework to generate installers, like MSI (see [How can I create an MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042566/how-can-i-create-an-msi-setup)) or [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page).