# How does a (windows) installer contain files?

Tags: installation

Just wondering how an installer such as a setup.exe contains the files it's supposed to install, when it's an offline installer. I get that I can create a msi or a setup.exe easily in Visual Studio, but what if I, for example, would want to write an installer with a custom gui with raw c++ (if possible)? How does a singular executable contain all the necessary files (such as the dll's)?

Comment: Installation for Windows apps can get really complex. What's the use case for reiinventing the wheel yourself instead of using one of the many free installation builders like Inno Setup?

Answer (score 0):

As Ken said, Windows Installer is a complex service. If you are into learning about it here are some resources:

**Intro for Windows Installer:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-portal

**How files are bundled inside an MSI:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/using-cabinets-and-compressed-sources

If you just want to [build a native MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042566/how-can-i-create-an-msi-setup) use existing tools, there are plenty of options free or paid.